# Why does the length of array shows zero when we define a set of array properties using character value instead of numeric?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was practicing JavaScript arrays, and I came across this situation. When I am declaring array properties using numeric values and I try to get the length of the array, then it shows the length. But when I set the properties of the array using character values, I get the length of the array as zero. Why is this happening?

```js
var array_1 = [];
var array_2 = [];

array_1[0] = "Hello World 1";
array_1[1] = "Hello World 2";
array_1[2] = "Hello World 3";
array_2['abc'] = "Hello World";
array_2['def'] = "Hello World 1";
array_2['ghi'] = "Hello World 2";
console.log(array_1.length);
console.log(array_2.length);
```

Answer (score 3):

As you can check in [here](https://www.dyn-web.com/javascript/arrays/associative.php):

> the length property as well as array methods are only applied to the elements with numeric indexes. Therefore, elements added using string indexes can only be regarded as properties of the array object and not true array elements.

Arrays are objects in javascript. So, you can think as adding string key elements to an array, as adding a new property to an object. This is why length will only work for array elements added with a numeric index.

Basically you can think the [array object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) is an extension of a [javascript object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) but with properties like push, remove or length that are exclusive to collection objects alike.

Check out the following example to understand better the usage in different scenarios:

```js
var array = [];

array[0] = 1;
// Length = 1
console.log(array.length);

array["five"] = 5;
// Length still = 1
console.log(array.length);

array[1] = 1;
// Length now is = 2
console.log(array.length);

array[4] = 1;
// Length now is = 5, because you are adding an element to the position 4
console.log(array.length);
console.log(array);
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Clear the doubt for this, but created another one. It makes a little confusion between objects and arrays. One will need to be careful.

Comment: @LalitPal Actually it is simple: array are objects, but objects are not arrays. So you basically can do everything with an array as you can do with objects, but the inverse is not valid.

Comment: @LalitPal you came from PHP, didn't you? :) Because in PHP associative arrays and numeric arrays are very close structures, but in JS array can only have numeric indexes, there is no such thing as associative arrays or hash-maps, they are basically objects. Well almost everything in JS is an object, Array is a particular case of the Object.

Comment: @Stalinko well, not exactly... I just came to this problem in JavaScript so I asked. I am not that much into PHP. And right now I have not studied associative arrays in PHP.